# How to do foreach Row in table (DataTables API)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am using [this thing](https://datatables.net/) in my .cshtml page.

By itself its working and I even has some actions, for example:

```
$("#Grid_grid tbody").on("dblclick", "tr", function () {
    var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Grid_grid");
    var card = dtApi.row(this).data();
    var uri = ActionResolver.GetActionUri("edit", card);            
    document.location = uri;
});
```

I need to do one more thing. When page is loaded I need to change color for several rows (according by one of stored values).

I managed to reproduce this for click action (just to see how it supposed to look):

```
$("#Grid_grid tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
    var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Grid_grid");
    var val = dtApi.row(this).data();
    if (val.Status == "Cancelled") {
        $(this).children('td, th').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    }
});
```

**BUT** I failed to do similar thing in this way:

```
$("#Grid_grid tbody").find('tr').each(function () {
    var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Grid_grid");
    var val = dtApi.row(this).data();
    if (val.Status == "Cancelled") {
        $(this).children('td, th').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    }
});
```

No reaction at all.

Thied to use [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) but also without a result.

What I am missing and what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have a specific table showup so I guess its already couted as a initialised before any script are runned.
I have this in .cshtml:

```
<div id="CardGridContainer" style="margin: 10px; background-color: white;">
    @Html.Action("CardsGrid", "Card")
</div>
```

This in Controller:

```
return Grid("Home.Cards", null, null);
```

and this in Home.Cards.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid>
  <Field name="OrderId" header="OrderId" hidden="true" />
  <Field name="OrderNo" header="Order Number" width="100" ungroupable="true"/> 
  <Field name="Status" header="Status" ungroupable="true" unsortable="true"/>
  <Field name="Specification" header="Specification"/>
  <Field name="DateRequired" header="Required Date" type="date" width="120" format="d"/>
  <Field name="CancelledStatus" header="Cancelled Status" width="100" ungroupable="true"/>
  <DataUrl>api/Data/Composition/CardViews</DataUrl>
  <QueryFilter>OrderId ne 0L</QueryFilter>
  <Ordering>Id asc</Ordering>
  <OrderingMode>single</OrderingMode>
  <AllowUnsort>false</AllowUnsort>
  <Height>500</Height>
  <Reorderable>true</Reorderable>
  <Groupable>true</Groupable>
  <Selectable>single</Selectable>
  <Paging>
    <PageSize>100</PageSize>
    <PageButtons>5</PageButtons>
    <RefreshButton>true</RefreshButton>
    <PageSizes>50,100,250,500</PageSizes>
  </Paging>
  <OnChange>
  <![CDATA[if (typeof nodes === "undefined") {
          ChangeSelection(null);
    }
    else {
          var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Grid_grid");
          ChangeSelection(dtApi.row(nodes[0]).data());
    }]]>
  </OnChange>
  <OnDataBound>
    <![CDATA[ChangeSelection(null);]]>
  </OnDataBound>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback of datatables ? Something like this

```
function tableLoaded() {
    $("#example tbody").find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff000');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "initComplete": tableLoaded
    });
});
```

A simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ebRXw/224/)

Comment: Started to get "cannot reinitialise datatable". Probably I shoul add it to question - My table are stored as a grid in *.config file and I am returning it from controller, so as I understand, its already counted as initialised one.

Comment: Looks like managed to deal with it when watched closer to my .config file. Added your tableLoaded to <OnDataBound> and it worked out. Thanks for giving Idea :D

Answer (score 0):

This will loop over the displayed rows

```
var items = $("#Grid_grid").dataTable().$("tr");            
$.each(items, function (index, row) {
    ...
})
```

You may want to run your highlighting code by setting a "drawCallback" function when you initialize the datatable.